# How do you update a DynamoDB table from PROVISIONED to PAY_PER_REQUEST in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an existing DDB table which uses `BillingMode: PROVISIONED` and `ProvisionedThroughput:{...}`. I want to change it to use `BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST` but when I do so I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReadCapacityUnits' of undefined
```

The parameters I'm sending to the `updateTable` call are:

```
{
  "TableName": "my-table-name",
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeType": "S",
      "AttributeName": "name"
    }
  ],
  "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
}
```

I also tried sending a `ProvisionedThroughput` field with the `ReadCapacityUnits` and `WriteCapacityUnits` in but this returned:

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ProvisionedThroughput cannot be specified when BillingMode is PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

... which is what I would expect from reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you are using aws cli, can you check the version? It seems like you are using old version of aws cli or sdk.

Comment: Lambda Node 10 Runtime so aws-sdk for JS version 2.437.0

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this was my mistake... to answer the question, you send exactly what I posted above, or just

```
{
  "TableName": "my-table-name",
  "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
}
```

... the "AttributeDefinitions" is unneeded as Nadav Har'El pointed out.

The problem was that in my lambda version I was building up the object to send based on what had changed and including `ProvisionedThroughput: undefined` which caused the SDK to try and validate this object. I did not see the problem for a long time because `console.log(JSON.stringify())` removes any keys whose value is `undefined`. To illustrate this another way:

```
$ node
> var a = {foo:1, bar:undefined}
undefined
> a
{ foo: 1, bar: undefined }
> console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
{"foo":1}
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

This **should work** for you, in https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.Basics.html there is an example:

`aws dynamodb update-table --table-name Music --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST`

The "AttributeDefinitions" part in your request seems superfluous, did you try without it?

Comment: I did try without it yes... strange thing is that I get the errors shown above when calling from a lambda but when I run a local node script with exactly the same call I get `LimitExceededException: Subscriber limit exceeded: Update to PayPerRequest mode are limited to once in 1 day(s). Last update at Thu May 23 11:14:37 UTC 2019` on that table... and with another similar table it worked fine (from the local script).

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question because I had a similar problem. 
Turns out I was using [CDK watchful](https://github.com/eladb/cdk-watchful) which kind of requires PROVISIONING MODE, with `readCapacity` and `writeCapacity` defined for the dynamo table. Once I'd done that, the `cdk diff`, `cdk synth` were happy again.